# How to declare custom taglib in ZK configuration

Tags: spring, taglib, zk

I have implemented my own custom taglib `utility.tld` then I put it under the WEB-INF folder and now I want to use it in my web application. This web is developed by ZK framework. I don't know where to declare my taglib `utility.tld` in the project to let the application understand my taglib definition.
I have tried to put it in web.xml like this:

```
  <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/utility.tld</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/utility.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
  </jsp-config>
```

But when accessing to the page which uses `utility.tld`, the server always throws this error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: jndi:/localhost//WEB-INF/utility.tld`
Could you please help me how to put this URI declaration to the exact configuration file and what is the correct syntax of this?
By the way, I have found this instruction and followed it, but nothing better happened.
http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/ZUML/Processing_Instructions/taglib/Custom_Taglib
Thank you!

Comment: That example shows you need a URI with the scheme/protocol specified, in <taglib-uri>. have you tried it as http:... your site... etc. ?

Comment: Yes Darius, I have tried with full scheme/protocol as you suggested, but it's still not OK. I think the problem here is the place to put my tag-lib declaration. My application does not use JSP, but ZUL to build the interface, and I guess maybe ZK framework need another way to specify what tag-lib used in application.

Comment: First, the taglib declaration should be inside `<config>` tag not `<jsp-config>` tag and also you have to put this taglib declaration inside `WEB-INF/classes/metainfo/tld/config.xml` file
Second, can you show us code snippet about how you are using this utility.tld in your zul page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From [the related article](http://ben-bai.blogspot.tw/2013/06/zk-custom-taglib.html))

You can define taglib in two ways:

- Put tld file under WebContent, and specify it in zul file with "/PATH/TO/YOUR/TLDFile" directly.

Note the path here starts from WebContent so you can specify it as "/WEB-INF/..."

- Put tld file under classpath, and specify it in classpath/metainfo/tld/config.xml with a specific URI, and specify the specific URI in zul file.

Note the path specified in config.xml starts from classpath, the tld file should under the classpath of your web project or in a jar file.

For more information, please refer to the sample project:

[TaglibTest](https://github.com/benbai123/ZK_Practice/tree/master/General/TaglibTest)

Comment: Actually I can start my application normally without specifying the TLD file in config.xml (and also no need to create this config file). I just put my packaged WAR to Tomcat's webapps folder, and the application can be run normally. But when I use Tomcat plugin in Eclipse, this error still happens. What is the difference between these 2 environments?

Comment: probably the spec are different, I experienced similar issue of jetty 1.1.x, it is caused by some files (say /META-INF/xxx.tld) will be loaded automatically in tomcat but not in jetty 1.1.x, refer to https://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/issues/detail?id=120&can=1&start=100.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @benbai123. So do we have any work-around solution to make it runnable on Eclipse with Tomcat plugin? Because running on WAR file at Tomcat's webapp folder won't allow me to debug the source code.

Comment: Doesn't the sample project work? It works well for me with rjr 1.1.x and Tomcat 6.0 in Eclipse (Helios SR2 with jdk7), probably because I'm using Tomcat directly (right click in 'Servers' -> New -> Add a Tomcat directory) instead of using a plugin? What I do is described at http://ben-bai.blogspot.tw/2012/06/zk-quick-start.html btw I suggest Run-Jetty-Run for debugging in Eclipse

Comment: Hi benbai123. Thank you for your analyzing about this problem. That's exactly what I've got. I changed the web server to jetty instead of Tomcat and run by this command "mvn jetty:run" (I forgot the configuration info in POM file), and my life is beautiful again. :D
BTW, your example and explanation are very clear and helpful to me. Thank you again.